# How to prevent Combobox from selecting first item on databinding to DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

How to prevent Combobox to select first item on databinding to DataSource.

I also have a datagridview table - where when the user selects a row on of the cells goes into the combobox - but I want it to override what ever is in the combobox with item from the table.

I have

```
PD.ItemCBx.Text = this.cOrdersDGV.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

from form1 which fills the combobox. 
But when form 2 is opened the combobox is filled with the first item on the databinding to DataSource.

I've tried

```
ItemCBx.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

but this stops the data being transfered.

Comment: Like your other questions, we're just going to have to see more code that can duplicate the problem for us.

Comment: `SelectedIndex = -1` worked for me. This code is found after I set the `DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, and `ValueMember`.

Answer (score -1):

"The way you "deselect" an item in a drop-down ComboBox is by selecting a different item."

"There is no "deselect" option for a ComboBox—something always has to be selected."

"If you want to simulate the behavior where nothing is selected, you'll need to add a  item (or equivalent) to the ComboBox."

"The user can then select this option when they want to "deselect"."

Check out the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25329202/9808334

Comment: I am not trying to deselect an item.