# ComboBox items are just a path

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Why are the ComboBox item's just a path?
When I start the appl. and want to select an item from the combobox, the items are just a path. It's every time the same path, the path to the class.

Here the Code where i give the combobox the items:

```
drpdefContVal.Items.AddRange(Controllertype.GetAll().ToArray<Controllertype>());
drpdefContVal.ValueMember = ((controllerType = Controllertype.GetByID(CoreClass.Settings.dbDEFAULTCONTROLLERTYPEID)) != null) ? controllerType.dbTitle : "";
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the display member property?

Comment: Is this a web application?

Comment: @Darren Yes. The combobox is just empty then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value Member is only one half of the coin with combo boxes.

You want to specify a Data member. This is the string property that will display for the list of items.

So within your  class I assume that the string value you want to bind to is the .

Thus you want to set the Display Member property like so:

```
drpdefContVal.DisplayMember = "dbTitle";
```

Comment: You should also see [PraVn's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522038/681819) answer for a bit more of a description.

Comment: Now the combobox is just empty.

Comment: did you set the drpdefContVal.DataSource = Controllertype.GetAll().ToArray<Controllertype>()

Comment: Thanks @Helix88 it worked wth
drpdefContVal.DataSource = Controllertype.GetAll().ToArray<Controllertype>()

But I found an other way with a method: 
    public override string ToString(){ return this.dbTitle; }