# How to add a custom index in ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm looking for some help, I'm new with C# and i'm trying to make a `combobox` with custom indexes, I was adding the `items` this way

```
mycb.Items.Add("My value 1");
mycb.Items.Add("My value 2");
```

by this way I get these indexes by default **`0 and 1`** so I try to give the indexes that I want to the `CB` using `Insert`

```
mycb.Items.Insert(5,"My value 1");
mycb.Items.Insert(6,"My value 2");
```

this way the `CB` should have the indexes **`5 and 6`** but this is not working because when I select one of those options this error appeared

***invalid argument=value of '5' is not valid for 'index'***

It works when I add consecutive indexes starting by 0 but that is not what I want, how can I add the indexes that I want to the `CB` without having this issue? I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: The indices of the first 2 items are `0` and `1`.  What you have is something else - an item value perhaps?  Thinking of them as an index isnt helpful because as you documented, you cant use 5 and/or 6 as an index to retrieve the first or second item.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow yes I know they are 0 and 1 but I want to give the indexes 5 and 6, how can i do that without that error?, those are two ways I tried to add custom indexes, right now I'm using the second way to achieve it not both, I need to use the indexes I want

Comment: Indexes are a "Read Only" property of a collection, so you can't set them to be anything than what they are.  The "Index" parameter in the "Insert" function allows you to control where you do the insert within the collection, it's not setting the index.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

You would make a dictionary (or array) of the items, assign it as the datasource for the combobox and set the "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" of the combobox, like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

myDictionary.Add(1, "string");
myDictionary.Add(2, "string2");
myDictionary.Add(4, "string4");

mycb.DataSource = myDictionary.ToArray();

mycb.DisplayMember = "Value";
mycb.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Comment: thank you! to make it even better:
1) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006620/2323103), `mycb.DataSource =` should be the last line.
2) I had to use `mycb.DataSource = new BindingSource(myDictionary, null)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding object instead of custom index?

Referring to [MSDN ComboBox.Items documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.items?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_Items)

> Although the ComboBox is typically used to display text items, you can add any object to the ComboBox. Typically, the representation of an object in the ComboBox is the string returned by that object's ToString method. If you want to have a member of the object displayed instead, choose the member that will be displayed by setting the DisplayMember property to the name of the appropriate member. **You can also choose a member of the object that will represent the value returned by the object by setting the ValueMember property**. For more information, see ListControl.

Code from [MSDN ListControl.ValueMember documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
ArrayList USStates = new ArrayList();
USStates.Add(new USState("Alabama", "AL"));
USStates.Add(new USState("Washington", "WA"));
USStates.Add(new USState("West Virginia", "WV"));
USStates.Add(new USState("Wisconsin", "WI"));
USStates.Add(new USState("Wyoming", "WY"));
ListBox1.DataSource = USStates;
```