# C# WindowsForm Combobox showing wrong "Display Value"

Tags: c#

**Goal:**

- Get all file directories from MySQL and place them into a dictionary.
- Display them into a combobox just as the filename. e.g. `filename`
- Assign the combobox value as the the full directory. e.g. `c:\users\user\desktop\filename.jpg`

**Code:**

```
string filenames = "select filename from  request_label_signoff where progress_user1 is null or progress_user2 is null";

//On load - load specific images from query above
private void Form15_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Dict to store file into
    Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(filenames, conn))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {   
                    //add filename without extension and full directory
                    files.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(reader.GetString(0)), reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }

    }

        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(files, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

}




private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(value);

}
```

**Problem:**

For some reason the display value for the combobox shows like this:

[image]

Text output: `[abc 123, C:\Users...]`

Whereas it should be `abc 123` without the directory next to it.

**Question:**

Why does he combo-box display value show both items?

Comment: It seems that you are populating the combobox in a wrong way. Google for information how to populate combobox or use this SO question as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423911/how-to-populate-c-sharp-windows-forms-combobox

Comment: [Other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507008/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this: `Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

I have used: `var choices = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

As guided in the comment by [hans-passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant])

And everything works. Not sure what the difference was.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of assignment in the combobox.

The reasons are:

> - sometimes the displaymember assignment wont work. [From
>     StackOverflow Answer
>     comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412739/binding-combobox-using-dictionary-as-the-datasource).
> - Sometimes, selectedIndex event might fire if you set datasource first. [Reference Stackoverflow
>     Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521980/combobox-valuemember-and-displaymember)

**Instead of:**

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(files, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

**it should be:**

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(files, null);
```

Comment: hmm... I tried. It is working fine for me. Debug it and see which is getting loaded to files dictionary

Comment: If I set `DisplayMember` to value. It just shows the Directory. But the key is showing the both values in these brackets `[]`